# Index PHP downloaded instead of executing it

Tags: php, apache, nginx, centos

I updated my server with php 7.4 however it created some issues my website couldn't be live again, the issue started after resinstalling httpd or installing httpd-devel not sure
I have bitrix managing my websites however the application is also hosted on the server and not deployed whenever I tried to access it, it downloads the php file, I need at least that to be running again

Environment :

Centos 7

PHP7.4

httpd -v : Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)

nginx -v : nginx version: nginx/1.16.1

I tried with "AddType" and "AddHandler" but no chance

I tried removing htaccess and recreating same issue

I can't find LoadModule php so module, even in module files so I haven't tried that option or I don't know where to start

Example of conf file of one of my website :

```
# Ansible managed
# site: medrec.org
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8887>
    ServerName  medrec.org
        ServerAlias www.medrec.org
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot  /home/bitrix/ext_www/medrec.org/public

        ErrorLog logs/medrec_error_log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog logs/medrec_access_log combined

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                #Nginx should have "proxy_set_header HTTPS YES;" in location
                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTPS} =YES
                RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTPS:on,L]
        </IfModule>




        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

        <DirectoryMatch .*\.svn/.*>
        Require all denied
        </DirectoryMatch>

        <DirectoryMatch .*\.git/.*>
                 Require all denied
        </DirectoryMatch>

        <DirectoryMatch .*\.hg/.*>
                 Require all denied
        </DirectoryMatch>

        <Directory /home/bitrix/ext_www/medrec.org/public>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
                AddType  application/x-httpd-php         .php
                AddType  application/x-httpd-php-source  .phps
        Require all granted

        #php_admin_value session.save_path /tmp/php_sessions/ext_www/medrec.org
        #php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir    /tmp/php_upload/ext_www/medrec.org
        </Directory>
<Directory /home/bitrix/ext_www/medrec.org/bitrix/cache>
                AllowOverride none
        Require all denied
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/bitrix/ext_www/medrec.org/bitrix/managed_cache>
                AllowOverride none
        Require all denied
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/bitrix/ext_www/medrec.org/bitrix/local_cache>
                AllowOverride none
        Require all denied
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/bitrix/ext_www/medrec.org/bitrix/stack_cache>
                AllowOverride none
        Require all denied
        </Directory>
<Directory /home/bitrix/ext_www/medrec.org/upload>
                AllowOverride none
                #AddType text/plain php,php3,php4,php5,php6,phtml,pl,asp,aspx,cgi,dll,exe,ico,shtm,shtml,fcg,fcgi,fpl,asmx,pht
                AddType  application/x-httpd-php         .php
                AddType  application/x-httpd-php-source  .phps
                #php_value engine off
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/bitrix/ext_www/medrec.org/upload/support/not_image>
                AllowOverride none
        Require all denied
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/bitrix/ext_www/medrec.org/bitrix/images>
                AllowOverride none
                #AddType text/plain php,php3,php4,php5,php6,phtml,pl,asp,aspx,cgi,dll,exe,ico,shtm,shtml,fcg,fcgi,fpl,asmx,pht
                AddType  application/x-httpd-php         .php
                AddType  application/x-httpd-php-source  .phps
                #php_value engine off
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/bitrix/ext_www/medrec.org/bitrix/tmp>
                AllowOverride none
                AddType text/plain php,php3,php4,php5,php6,phtml,pl,asp,aspx,cgi,dll,exe,ico,shtm,shtml,fcg,fcgi,fpl,asmx,pht
                #php_value engine off
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

httpd.conf

```
ServerTokens OS
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
PidFile run/httpd.pid

# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.

Timeout 120

# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.

KeepAlive Off

# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.

KeepAliveTimeout 15

<IfModule worker.c>
        StartServers         2
        MaxClients         150
        MinSpareThreads     25
        MaxSpareThreads     75
        ThreadsPerChild     25
        MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>

# Active module

Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
<IfModule setenvif_module>
    SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Scheme https HTTPS=on
    SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
</IfModule>

#
# Disabled standart config
#

#Include conf.d/*.conf

#
# BitrixEnv include configs
#

Include bx/conf/*.conf
Include bx/custom/*.conf

User bitrix
Group bitrix

ServerAdmin root@localhost

UseCanonicalName Off

DocumentRoot "/home/bitrix/www"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        UserDir disable
</IfModule>

DirectoryIndex index.html
AccessFileName .htaccess

<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</Files>

TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
#ForceType text/plain
<IfModule mod_mime_magic.c>
        MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog logs/error_log

LogLevel warn
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
CustomLog logs/access_log combined

ServerSignature On

<IfModule mod_dav_fs.c>
        # Location of the WebDAV lock database.
        DAVLockDB /var/lib/dav/lockdb
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
        IndexOptions FancyIndexing VersionSort NameWidth=* HTMLTable
        IndexIgnore .??* *~ *# HEADER* README* RCS CVS *,v *,t
</IfModule>

AddLanguage ca .ca
(Laguages ...)

#LanguagePriority en ca cs da de el eo es et fr he hr it ja ko ltz nl nn no pl pt pt-BR ru sv zh-CN zh-TW
#ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

AddType application/x-compress .Z
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

AddHandler type-map var
AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml


BrowserMatch "Mozilla/2" nokeepalive
BrowserMatch "MSIE 4\.0b2;" nokeepalive downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "RealPlayer 4\.0" force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "Java/1\.0" force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "JDK/1\.0" force-response-1.0

#BrowserMatch "Microsoft Data Access Internet Publishing Provider" redirect-carefully
#BrowserMatch "MS FrontPage" redirect-carefully
#BrowserMatch "^WebDrive" redirect-carefully
#BrowserMatch "^WebDAVFS/1.[0123]" redirect-carefully
#BrowserMatch "^gnome-vfs/1.0" redirect-carefully
#BrowserMatch "^XML Spy" redirect-carefully
#BrowserMatch "^Dreamweaver-WebDAV-SCM1" redirect-carefully
```

**Update**
Liste of confs in conf.modules.d

[image]

15-php.conf

[image]

Modules

[image]

Comment: Are you running Apache or Nginx as your web server?

Comment: @RamanSailopal  Im running nginx, no apache2 or php-fpm services, Im using httpd (apachectl)

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You say you are running Nginx with httpd? Is it one or the other?

Comment: Yes, both services shouldbe up,if I stop one of them it doesn't run at all

Comment: it was running smoothly until I updated php version, tbh its not my configuration and I can't contact the previous manager

Comment: As already pointed out, your question does not make a lot of sense. Apache and nginx are both web servers, you are almost certainly running only one of them, but not both (unless you have a more complex proxying config which you have not mentioned).  If you don't know which, use your browser devtools and view the headers of a network request, it will show you which server handled that request.  Having said all that, the Apache config you have shown does not seem to include a `LoadModule` for PHP.  How did you install PHP 7.4?

Comment: What further configuration is hidden in`Include conf.modules.d/*.conf` and maybe  `Include bx/conf/*.conf` and 
`Include bx/custom/*.conf`

Comment: My guess would be that in the folder `conf.modules.d` there is a file for php that includes something simular to `LoadModule php_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp8.0.so` where php_module might needs to be php7_module now and the so file will be called different

Comment: @Don'tPanic I guess the proxying has been made by bitrix24 our server app which doesn't work now to manipulate apps in the server, I installed it using yum install/update I changed the remi package to 7.4

Comment: @Mazaka I don't have apache2 in my server I can only access httpd directory libphp7.0.so is already loaded in the conf.modules.d

Comment: @AnouarKacem can you share the line that loads php module. oh and as far as i know httpd is the same as apache2 just diff name because i copied from debian

Comment: @AnouarKacem weird question could it be that your browser keeps loading the file from cache? Chrome specificly did weird thing to me in the past. To be honost after such a long time I would just move the Apache/httpd config to a safe place and reinstall apache and php and do a quick test see if it work and then work from there.

Comment: Well I had to reinstall the app, downgrade php to 7.2 rewrite all configs and made it work although still don't know what was causing the problem, thank you for your efforts

Comment: Check my answer. You missed setHandler in your config files.

Answer (score 2):

### Your modules seems to be messed up.

Check if php7 module is loaded:

```sh
# apachectl -M | grep -i php
php7_module (shared)
```

In your *httpd.conf*, php7 modules are loaded by including existings files in *conf.modules.d* directory.

The `libphp7-zts.so` means Thread Safe.
And your Apache don't seems to like it.

You are only setting MIME types with lines below:

```
AddType  application/x-httpd-php         .php
AddType  application/x-httpd-php-source  .phps
```

To handle PHP, you need to **set handlers**.

So replace your 15-php.conf file with this:

```
LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so
<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced similar issues
Try

```
sudo apt-get install php7.x libapache2-mod-php7.x
```

will install everything you need and will start the server with support for PHP.

verify if php module is loaded correctly using:

```
a2query -m php7.x
```

if not , load it using

```
sudo a2enmod php7.x
```

Type the following command:

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

OR

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Also

The correct AddType for php is application/x-httpd-php

```
AddType  application/x-httpd-php         .php
AddType  application/x-httpd-php-source  .phps
```

Comment: I m using centos 7, even using yum install, there are no packages with those names

Comment: Try refering this link , https://www.tecmint.com/install-php-7-in-centos-7/